# C boolean function comparing 2 Strings alphabeticly

Tags: c, string, string-comparison

So I am trying to compare 2 strings and if the first one (x) is smaller than the second one the method twoStrComp should return true, else it should be false.

This is my code, although when I try to run it on my terminal nothing comes up...
As if it ignored my code.. Also I was wondering if it would be more efficient with pointers but I was unsure of how to declare them, can I do twoStrComp(*x,*y)?
ORIGINAL CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool twoStrComp(char[], char[]);

int main(void)
{
  char x[]= "test";
  char y[]= "another";
  twoStrComp(x,y);      
}

bool twoStrComp(char string1[], char string2[] )
{
  int i=0, flag=0;    
  while(flag==0)
  {
    if (string1[i]<string2[i])
    {
      flag=-1;
    }
    else if (string1[i]==string2[i])
    {
      flag=0;
      i++
    }
    else
    {
      return 1;
    }
  }         
  return flag;
}
```

new VERSION:

```
bool twoStrComp(char[], char[]);

int main(void)
{
    char x[]= "atest";
    char y[]= "another";
    bool ans = twoStrComp(x,y);
    printf("%s", ans ? "true" : "false");

}

bool twoStrComp(char string1[], char string2[] )
{
    int i=0, flag=0;
    bool value = false;
       while(flag==0) {
        if (string1[i]>string2[i])
        {
            flag=1;
            value = false;
        }
        else if (string1[i]<string2[i])
        {
            flag=-1;
            value = true;
        }
        else if (string1[i]==string2[i])
        {
            return 0;
            value = true;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1)
        return (value == false);
    if(flag == -1)
        return (value == true);
 return value;
}
```

Comment: You're calling `twoStrComp`, then you're discarding the result and silently exiting.  What would you like to do instead?  Perhaps print something?  Do you know how to use `printf`?

Comment: @TomKarzes oh wow! I thought I was return flag a boolean (true or false) so it would print true or false. If x < y then flag == true, if x>y then flag == false. mmh for printf, would it be printf(" %s \n", twoStrComp(x,y)); ?

Comment: What were you expecting to see in your terminal? Why do you think that nothing was printed to the terminal?  Is there a place in your program where you are printing the results of your comparison function?

Comment: Look at the call to `twoStrComp`.  You're dropping the return value on the floor.  It doesn't matter *what* `twoStrComp` returns, because you're ignoring it.

Comment: Comparing 2 characters of a string can yield 3 different results: less, equal, greater. Your final `else` part will never be reached. Instead you will return 0 if you find the first 2 matching characters.

Comment: @Gerhardh I edited the code, would that be better?

Comment: Editing the question is discouraged as it might void some or all comments and answers up to that point. And no, your edit made it worse.

Comment: @Gerhardh Ah sorry.. Well I really don't know :/

Comment: And another edit voiding my comments. No one wants to aim at a moving target.

Comment: ? I don't understand your claim. I am just trying to get help better understanding C as I am only used to Java :/

Comment: Please don't just mess around with the code in your question. Now it doesn't even compile. Please first read comments, think about it, change your code, check the result. Then update the question. Preferrably with adding new code instead of changing existing parts.

Comment: Ok I will add under the code I have now Although I think i made it worst... I tried to add all your comments

Comment: `return 0; value = true;` Don't you get some warning for that line?

Comment: No i wasn't getting an error, I was getting a true or false as an answer. Thank you for code! I am trying to build on it because somehow it keeps answering FALSE, my console doesn't recognize the TRUE, FALSE I can't tell why...

Comment: You should always enable all warnings. Your compiler should give some hint about dead code after `return`.

Answer (score 1):

> So I am trying to compare 2 strings and if the first one (x) is smaller than the second one the method twoStrComp should return true, else it should be false.

I suggest a better name for your function. It is no generic compare function but it's more a `isSmaller` function. You don't care about separate cases for identical or larger values.

> This is my code, although when I try to run it on my terminal nothing comes up

If you want to see anything on your console, you need to print something. You can use `printf` for that purpose.

> Also I was wondering if it would be more efficient with pointers but I was unsure of how to declare them, can I do twoStrComp(*x,*y)?

If you want to pass pointers, you can declare it like this:

```
bool twoStrComp(const char *x, const char *y)
```

But....
Passing arrays as parameters results in passing pointers anyway. The array decays to pointers when used in parameter list of a function. You won't see any performance improvement.

Regarding your code...
I refer to the version listed as version 2 in edit history.

You return 1 or -1. As you use type `bool` for return type, you should think about using `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Or at least return 0 in some case.

Setting `flag=0;` does not have any sense. If it wasn't 0 before, you would have left the loop.

You don't check whether you compare beyond the end of the strings.

A version that fixes those problems and includes some test cases could look like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool twoStrComp(char string1[], char string2[]);

int main(void)
{
  char x[]= "test";
  char y[]= "another";
  bool isSmaller = twoStrComp(x,y);
  printf("Is x(%s) smaller than y(%s)? %s\n", x, y, isSmaller ? "YES" : "NO");

  isSmaller = twoStrComp(y,x);
  printf("Is y(%s) smaller than x(%s)? %s\n", y, x, isSmaller ? "YES" : "NO");

  char x2[]= "aaa";
  char y2[]= "aab";

  isSmaller = twoStrComp(x2,y2);
  printf("Is x2(%s) smaller than y2(%s)? %s\n", x2, y2, isSmaller ? "YES" : "NO");

  isSmaller = twoStrComp(y2,x2);
  printf("Is y2(%s) smaller than x2(%s)? %s\n", y2, x2, isSmaller ? "YES" : "NO");

  isSmaller = twoStrComp(x2,x2);
  printf("Is x2(%s) smaller than x2(%s)? %s\n", x2, x2, isSmaller ? "YES" : "NO");
}

bool twoStrComp(char string1[], char string2[])
{
  int i=0;
  while (true)
  {
    if (string1[i] < string2[i])
      return true; // First one smaller than second one...
    else if (string1[i] > string2[i])
      return false; // First one larger than second one...
    else if (!string1[i])
      return false; // identical and end of strings reached.
    else
      i++;   // identical, not yet decided.
  }

  // We cannot get here, but the compiler complains...
  return false;         
}
```